# NetBeans Gradle shadow dependency not added at runtime

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans, gradle-shadow-plugin

I've imported a Gradle project into NetBeans 12.4. This project uses shadow plugin and sets the JDBC driver as a shadow excluded dependency:

```
shadow files('lib/sqljdbc.jar')
```

When I hit the Run or Debug button in NetBeans, the program fails when trying to load the JDBC driver. How can I tell NetBeans or Gradle to include "shadow" dependencies when running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file "gradle.properties", add the following line:

```
action.run.args=runShadow ${javaExec.jvmArgs} ${javaExec.args}
```